# How can we get data from iOS device using USB commands when its connected with Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, usb, libusb

When any iOS Device connected with Mac, I want device's all data in Custom developed desktop app (not Itunes), I want data like installed app list, all settings list, all installed provisioning profile list, all media content (iBooks, News, Videos, Music etc.), running application list, current screen of applications with the help of USB commands. In other words, I want all data (the data which we can take from iTunes) in my desktop app with the help of USB Commands. Is there any way to send USB commands to iOS device and get requested data from it?

Thanks in advice for your time and reply.

Comment: I think you can't... not "legally". This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678681/usb-programming-with-objective-c
And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847364/can-my-iphone-app-communicate-with-a-connected-computer

Comment: Thanks Paul Peelen for your quick reply. I appreciate it.